# office365 autodiscover 401 via POX API but successful over testexchangeconnectivity.com

Tags: objective-c, outlook, exchangewebservices, office365

I have a situation where I am trying to handle auto discover in an iOS app (GOD I HATE auto discover with a passion). I'm at this point where I have followed through several sequences of redirects and email aliases, and the auto discover is now pointing me to an Office 365 URL (this user has been migrated to Office365).

I'm seeing a HTTP redirect to https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com, and I'm POST-ing the standard POX to https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml with the user's credentials. I'm getting a 401 in return. I'm also getting a 401 when I curl this manually.

My POST is to https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. This is authenticated using the users email and password (I'm using AFNetworking 2.0, so I'm using the HTTPRequestSerilizer authentication mechanism)

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
<Request>
<EMailAddress>user@Service.domain.com</EMailAddress>
<AcceptableResponseSchema>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a</AcceptableResponseSchema>
</Request>
</Autodiscover>
```

The response that I get is:

> Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x8be9280 {
>           NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml, 
>           AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= 
>           { 
>               URL: https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml 
>           }
>           { status code: 401,
>             headers {
>                 "Cache-Control" = private;
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       Date = "Thu, 06 Mar 2014 05:00:49 GMT";
>       RequestId = "ee723790-60db-4008-b800-7d44d9884498";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
>       "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic Realm=\"\"";
>       "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
>       "X-DiagInfo" = BLUPRD0810CA020;
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>   } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}

I get the same error when I try to CURL the same post data with the same user and password.

However, when I go to testexchangeconnectivity.com, I see the following, which I don't receive through the POX APIs:

> Test Steps
>
> The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to retrieve an XML Autodiscover response from URL https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml for user user@Service.domain.com.
>
> The Autodiscover XML response was successfully retrieved.
>   Additional Details
>
> An HTTPS redirect was received in response to the Autodiscover request. The redirect URL is https://pod51008.outlook.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

Is there something wrong that I'm doing? I think the credentials work, because the initial auto discover to the user's on premise domain resolves fine and sends me online. The fact that curl also doesn't work leads me to think that there is some special office365 authentication that I'm not doing properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem. I received an email address change from Autodiscover indicating that I should go from user@domain.com to user@service.domain.com. I then re-built the auto discover urls using user@service.domain.com. However, I was authenticating with user@service.domain.com, not user@domain.com. This is why I received 401.

I hate auto discover. None of this is documented anywhere (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj900154(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj900155(v=exchg.150).aspx contains information on restarting Autodiscover with the RedirectTarget (SOAP) or RedirectAddr (POX).

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what is going on without seeing every request and response. What is the structure of the Office365 URL?

Did you try an un-authenticated GET request to `"http://autodiscover." + domain + "/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"`? In [Autodiscover for Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj900169%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), there is a Phase 3 sub section that describes this. This article captures much of the requirements for implementing auto discover for a client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been following the spec as best as I can and I've gotten through several "redirects" already. I'll edit my post with the relegate request/response bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I think Michael meant to link to [Handling Autodiscover error messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467392%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). However, it doesn't explicitly note that you should not change your user name in your credentials when you get a redirect to another email address. You only change it in the EMailAddress element. Thanks for the feedback, and sorry for the confusion!